# Angularjs-ui-router: How to activate default views on app start up?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 states in my app currently. Each app has multiple views. I want on state to be activated on app start up. Right now, when the app starts, I only get the links. Then I have to click on any link to activate any state. How do I make a state opened by default?

**states conf**

```
var app = angular.module('dategenie', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'geolocation', 'ngIdle', 'infinite-scroll']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /profile
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider.state('profile', {
    views: {
      mainModule: {
        url : '/profile'
        , templateUrl : 'partials/profile.html'
        , controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      }
      , rightPaneModule: {
        templateUrl: 'partials/location.html'
        , controller: 'LocationCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('profiles', {
    views: {
      mainModule: {
        url : '/'
        , templateUrl : 'partials/home.html'
        , controller : 'HomeCtrl'
      }
      , chatModule: {
        templateUrl : 'partials/chat.html'
        , controller: 'ChatCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
a(ui-sref="profile") Profile
a(ui-sref="profiles") Home
a(href="/logout") Logout
div(ui-view="mainModule")
div(ui-view="chatModule")
div(ui-view="rightPaneModule")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your url declaration should be outside of the views object.

So this is how your profiles state would look like:

```
.state('profiles', {
  url : '/',
  views: {
    mainModule: {
      templateUrl : 'partials/home.html'
      , controller : 'HomeCtrl'
    }, 
    chatModule: {
      templateUrl : 'partials/chat.html'
      , controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if this is still a valid concern, but I would put all of my view names in quotes. If memory serves me right, this had some implications earlier on with UI-router - not sure if that still applies.

Secondly, you need to make sure you have HTML5 Pushstate enabled if you wish for routing to pick up an active state on "/". Otherwise your 'root' would be "/#/".

Here's some code you can slap in say a push-state.js file;

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  return $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Quite useful to have in it's own file when you stumble upon errors with client side routing, I find most of my issues arise from PushState indescrepencies (so toggling it on and off is a nice little advantage when debugging).

Hope that works out for you, good luck : )